# Hour Wise data in mySql

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, time-series, aggregate-functions

I have the table with following fields

```
Createdon(datetime)
Amount(double)
```

I need to find the sum of amounts for next 24 hours of the given date. If there are no results then the sum should be zero. 
e.g

```
duration  sum
0000-0001 25.43
0001-0002 36.85
0002-0003 0
.
.
.
.
0022-0023 38.56
```

Can you please help me creating a query to find the required solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to your query is the ability to take any `datetime` value and truncate it to the nearest preceding hour. You can do that with this expression:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
```

Given, for example, `2015-04-21 14:22:05`, this gives back `2015-04-21 14:00:00`.

Then you use that in GROUP BY

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00') Createdhour,
       SUM(Amount) sum
  FROM theTable
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
 ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
```

Finally, I think you wanted one day's worth of results.  You need to add a `WHERE` clause to get that. The one shown here will take yesterday's results -- that is, all results from [midnight yesterday -- midnight today).

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00') Createdhour,
       SUM(Amount) sum
  FROM theTable
 WHERE CreatedOn >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND CreatedOn <  DATE(NOW())
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
 ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
```

This is explained in greater detail at http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

To include all hours of the day, you will need an independent source of distinct `DATETIME` items.

Here's a query that will do such a thing.

```
      SELECT mintime + INTERVAL seq.seq HOUR AS CreatedHour
        FROM (
              SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS mintime,
                     DATE(NOW()) AS maxtime
             ) AS minmax
        JOIN seq_0_to_23 AS seq 
              ON seq.seq < TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,mintime,maxtime)
```

You then need to use `LEFT JOIN` to pick up your data.

```
SELECT a.Createdhour,
       SUM(Amount) sum
  FROM (
      SELECT mintime + INTERVAL seq.seq HOUR AS CreatedHour
        FROM (
              SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS mintime,
                     DATE(NOW()) AS maxtime
             ) AS minmax
        JOIN seq_0_to_23 AS seq 
              ON seq.seq < TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,mintime,maxtime)
       ) a
  LEFT JOIN theTable t 
          ON a.CreatedHour  = DATE_FORMAT(t.Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
 ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(t.Createdon, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00')
```

Finally, you need to somehow get that table `seq_0_to_23`.  If you're running MariaDB, it's built in. If not...

```
CREATE TABLE seq_0_to_23 AS
 SELECT 0 AS seq 
  UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
  UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
  UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
  UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
  UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
  UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
  UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
```

This is written up in more general form at http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It does Work but the catch is that I need the sum **zero** if there are no records. I am getting 22 rows not the 24.

Comment: Filling in the missing times is considerably hairier. See my edit.